# How to stop waking all attached drives on reboot / deactivating swap?

Tags: debian, power-management, swap

A fresh install of Debian 6.0.6 for a system has 13 SATA drives attached. 12 refurbished WD-10EARS drives are yet unpartitioned. 1 WD1500BLFS drive is configured for OS and swap. Swap partition is configured on /dev/sda5 according /etc/fstab

```
root@debian:~# cat /etc/fstab | grep swap
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=641cc8ad-838d-4e92-8c2c-0b73359a5aa3 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Because the 12 drives have no disk activity, the drive state goes from "active/idle" to "standby" after a while.

```
root@debian:~# hdparm -C /dev/sdm

/dev/sda:
 drive state is:  active/idle

root@debian:~# hdparm -C /dev/sdm

/dev/sda:
 drive state is:  standby
```

When issueing a `reboot` command the console shows "`Deactivating swap...`" and then staggered all 12 drives start to spinup as verified by sound and power consumption. Having a drive state change from standby to active can take up to 30 seconds. In other words a reboot now takes between 3 and 7 minutes. How long would a reboot take when 70 drives are attached!

*Update #1*
The issue is related to "sd" (storage device) that wishes to "**Synchronizing SCSI cache**" on each drive.

How to stop changing all drives its state from "standby" to "active" on reboot (most likely caused by the "deactivating swap" process)?

```
# uname -mrsn
Linux debian 2.6.32-5-amd64 x86_64
```

Comment: 30 seconds for a drive to spin up? I knew the consumer-grade "green" drives were bad, but I guess I had no idea.

Comment: I don't believe that the deactivation of swap causes this. You can test that by issuing swapoff <partition> while the system is running.

Comment: After deactivating swap with `swapoff -a -v` (`swapoff /dev/sda5` fails with "swapoff failed: Invalid argument") there is still a message "`Deactivating swap...`" on `reboot` and all drives still spinup.

Comment: After a second reboot, the "Deactivating swap... Done" message is instantaneous. Also sleeping drives using `hdparm` is immediate instead of having a multi second delay.

Comment: The third reboot gives a "hanging" Deactivating swap... message. Later on followed by many errors like "end_request I/O error, dev sdb, sector {0, 8, 16, 128, 4096}". And also for sd{c,d,e,f,g,h,i,...}

Comment: The difference between "second" and "third" reboot, is that in "second" all drives were in state "active/idle", and in "third" reboot all drives were in state "standby".

Comment: The error message seems related to [debian bug#685009](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=685009). Where mptsas HDD fails to resume from standby in kernel 3.2 and 3.1. Let me go back to kernel version 3.0.

Comment: @ProBackup if that solves your problem make it an answer...

Comment: @jordanm Changing drive state from "standby" to "active/idle" takes 56 seconds for our eight WD-10EARS drives in total.

Comment: @BonsiScott You are right, the issue is not caused by swap, but by SCSI. After starting verbose the was a console message "Synchronizing SCSI cache" for each and every attached SCSI disk. Each sync causes the drive to spin up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing to backports kernel 3.2.0-0.bpo.3-amd64 there is no longer a wake of all drives between issuing `reboot` and message `Will now restart.` appears, with or without swap being enabled.

Note that the console "end_request I/O error, dev sdb, sector {0, 8, 16, 128, 4096}" error messages are still there when the drives are in standby state.

*Update #1*

The "Synchronizing SCSI cache before rebooting" issue re-appears in 3.2.0-0.bpo.**4**-amd64. Although both seem to share the same version of the mpt2sas module:

```
# modinfo /lib/modules/3.2.0-0.bpo.{3,4}-amd64/kernel/drivers/scsi/mpt2sas/mpt2sas.ko | grep ^version
version:        10.100.00.00
version:        10.100.00.00
```

*Update #2*

The issue doesn't seem to be kernel and storage module related. After changing back to kernel 2.6.32-5-amd64, setting all drives to standby, and commanding a reboot, there were no "Synchronizing SCSI cache", no drive spin ups, and therefore no delays.

*Update #3*

When turning off write cache `hdparm -W0 /dev/sd?` and flushing the write cache with `sync && sdparm --command=sync /dev/sd? && sleep 1` and finally setting the drive to standby using `hdparm -y /dev/sd?` then there is no "Synchronizing SCSI cache" for every drive after running `reboot` and seeing output "Mounting root filesystem read-only...done." and "Will now restart." when using:

1. Linux debian 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 10:07:46 UTC 2012 x86_64
2. Linux debian 3.2.0-0.bpo.3-amd64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 23 07:41:30 UTC 2012 x86_64

Kernel 3.2.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 is faulty and does "Synchronizing SCSI cache" for every drive on every `reboot`.

Comment: Due to drive renumbering (/dev/sda became /dev/sdi) I needed to use `swapoff -v -a` for a consistent halt where drives will not be taken out of their standby state.